# Should FindUsersByName include partial matches?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk59azhc.aspx) isn't precise on this point.

It says in one place: "Gets a collection of membership users where the user name **contains** the specified user name to match."

Later it says, "FindUsersByName  returns a list of membership users where the user name **matches** the supplied usernameToMatch for the configured applicationName."

The SQLMembershipProvider supports wildcards, but the documentation doesn't say whether I must also do so with my custom membership provider.

**Edit:** I'm really asking more about the intent of the Membership Provider rather than what I should do in my specific situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FindUsersByName function will do a match on the string you pass in.

If you want it to do a partial match then you need to add '%' on the end of the string you're searching for.

Answer (score 3):

This sentence in the documentation explains it:

```
The SqlMembershipProvider performs its search using a LIKE clause against the usernameToMatch parameter. Any wildcards that are supported by SQL Server in LIKE clauses can be used in the usernameToMatch parameter value.
```

SO

"Gets a collection of membership users where the user name **contains** the specified user name to match."

is the accurate sentence if you do a search for "DAV*" you should get "Dave", "David, "Davis", etc.

Comment: I understand that's how SqlMembershipProvider does it, but does this imply that all other implementations should support this?  Furthermore, am I expected to support LIKE wildcards?

Answer (score 0):

Let's make it more restrictive (find exact match) to be sure that user 'joe' has no access to data of the user 'joel' :)

Anyway, do you really need to find a user given only part of it's name?

EDIT:
Now checked again the MSDN method you linked to, and it's name is **FindUsersByName** (users, not user) so the method is able to return more than one user. It this case I assume you should implement the code to return all matches.
If the method would be **FindUserByName**, then it is the opposite answer (you have the method **GetUser** for this)

Comment: In an admin site, that's a common need.

Comment: As an admin I am still not convinced. Admin tasks are not so frequent in this matter, different methods can be applied.
The true answer should be: depends of your need :)